# set up of big integer library in a project

Tags: c++

I would like to try and test my programme with big integers since I get into stack overflow with long double variables and the error being showed is when my variables becomes too large followed by ...#DEN. I have downloaded the library from https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/ and copied all files from it into my cpp folder. And it accepted it. However, when I define a big integer variables it says

```
      error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BigInteger::BigInteger
      (int)" (??0BigInteger@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl pr(void)" (?pr@@YAXXZ)
```

How should I resolve that?

Comment: How did you build your program?

Comment: Did you include all the files in your project?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? Did you refresh the project after copying the files? Do the files show up inside visual studio (both the .hh and .cc files)?

Comment: Yes. I can see the files appearing in my project under show all files.

Comment: @user3017335 try doing a clean/rebuild/restart (or [try another one](https://github.com/Futsy/Euler/blob/master/LargeInt/LargeInt.h) (header only))